# Need to convert png files to one pdf file

Tags: php, linux, pdf, cmd

I have one folder logos and it contains 200 png image files. 
I need to convert all 200 ing file to one pdf. Please give me easy way to do it.
I am using below command but it gives corrupted pdf with some image displayed and some of the pages blank.
Please give me alternate command to run in my linux server.

```
convert *.png +compress logos.pdf
```

Comment: What does php have to do with this?

Comment: if any php code to convert it then provide it. I will run it with cron. @Daan

Comment: Then why only tag PHP and not for example Python ?

Comment: My current site developed in php and these image file folder exist there so i need it. @Daan

Comment: maybe use [mpdf](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf)? it supports images inside the pdf and you can add all the images in 1?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to generate PDF files with PHP is using some libraries. You can search about them in Packagist: https://packagist.org/search/?q=pdf

Another option is http://phptopdf.com/.

If you are using Laravel I recommend you to use DOMPDF (packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) or Snappy (github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/)

Comment: I need some linux/cmd command to generate pdf of .png files which stored in one folder.